# How can i use ui-select in ui-bootstrap modal while using Angular Formly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

How can i use ui-select in ui-bootstrap modal while using Angular Formly?

http://angular-formly.com/#/example/integrations/ui-bootstrap-modal --> this link contains the example, but here they have taken only input fields.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: Questions asking for help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I uses this in my code

```
var modelInstalnce = $uibModal.open({
templateUrl: '...',
scope: $scope,
controller: function($scope,$uibModalInstance){
    $scope.selectedValue = selectedValue;
    function selectedValue($search){
       $select.selected = $search.value;
    }
}
```

Html

```
on-select="selectedValue($select.selected);"
```